# Undo operation for TFS?

Tags: tfs, undo

I got the 'resolve' dialog in TFS, and it looks like I clicked too fast on the wrong button (because they're too close together) and blew away a week's worth of work when TFS discarded my local changes.  Is there an undo operation somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry.  There have been many proposals over the years to move undone changes (and deleted files, etc) to the Recycle Bin instead of blowing them away, but the feature always seems to land on the cutting block.  I'll see if there's an open request @ Connect where we can add our votes.

PS: shelve early, shelve often!

Comment: Any idea if this feature is still alive in some form or fashion?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. If you have overwritten your local files, changes are lost.
Sorry (and hopefully, I'll be faster when rewriting your code :))